# Android - Facebook Cancels

Tags: java, android, facebook

Every time I run my app and it tries to connect to facebook it cancels. It is already authroized and I can connect on my normal Facebook app. I have been looking for a solution for about two days now and can't find any. This is really the only problem holding me back from finishing my app... Hopefully I can get some answers.

I am using this [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Here is my facebook authorize code:

```
public void authFB(){
    Log.i("IN","FB - Authorizing");
    fb.authorize(this, new String[]{ "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", fb.getAccessToken());
            editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
            editor.putString("post_id",values.getString("post_id"));
            editor.commit();
            Log.i("IN","Login Successful");
            checkFB();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Log.i("IN","Login UnSuccessful - fb error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            checkFB();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.i("IN","Login UnSuccessful - error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            checkFB();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i("IN","Login UnSuccessful - cancel");
            checkFB();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my onCreate:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
    //String post_id = prefs.getString("post_id",null);
    long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires",0);
    if(access_token != null){
        fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0){
        fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if(!fb.isSessionValid()){
        authFB();
    }
```

I have ZERO ideas about what is wrong. I have tried it on two different phones now and this is the debug I get:

```
03-07 18:18:43.460: INFO/IN(6741): Login UnSuccessful - cancel
```

That means onCancel is being called.

CONFUSED.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself.
I kept getting this error because I had this in my manifest for my activities:

```
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

I am posting this because hopefully it will help someone in the future.

The reason why it created an error is because it tried to create a secondInstance (duh) and that isnt allowed.

Comment: twitter4j need singleInstance to authenticate, how can I handle twitter and facebook authentication on the same activity?

Comment: @CassioLandim Use Parse.com and their facebook and twitter implementation. And to Brandon, THANKS A TON!!! Wasted a lot of time on that.